# Function Running on App Service Plan Timeout

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

We have a v1 function running on App Service Plan, that when triggered under load ... say going from 0 work to 10,000 EventHub Triggers in a few seconds falls over itself.

The App Service Plan is running 2x S1 nodes, and set to scale to max of 5 nodes, which should be enough for just above our peak load currently..

What we are seeing though, is the two nodes get immediately overwhelmed, and the provisioning of new VMs simply isn't fast enough by which time Azure Functions just keep attempting to invoke functions, of which there are no resources to accommodate, and they all bomb out.

Are there ways to:

- Limit Function the invocations at all?
- Scale faster, the minimum window for auto-scale is 5mins(!)
- Throttle the EventHub throughput?
- Also, would moving to v2 Functions help at all (longshot)

**Update:**
To make it clear, i will state that the aim here is to simply ensure that the function doing work does not timeout when attempting to become invoked on App Service Plan.. i don't care if it runs out of resources on the machine.. it should just run slower you would have though?

Comment: did you change any batch size or prefect count setting in host.json file? If yes please share. default settings are https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json

Comment: Why not Consumption Plan? How many partitions on Event Hub?

Comment: @PankajRawat we have the default at the moment, i am considering reducing the batch size..

Comment: @Mikhail We have two functions that "do stuff", and then write to cosmosDb, and then two ChangeFeed functions that encrypt data and write that out to blob - due to the velocity of changes in some situations we were seeing the number of attempted connections from the ChangeFeed functions spike and we had to move to ASP to mitigate at the recommendation of Microsoft.

Comment: might need to switch my trouble CPU bound function (the one causing me pain) to consumption plan.. but then i have to manage to Function Apps, urgh

Comment: @m1nkeh yes try it (maybe with 1 batch and 1 prefetch count)

Comment: @PankajRawat hmm.. seems a backwards step after we spent time optimising it to take batches, and run them async in parallel.. :/